# Is there a way to update with exising field value using JDBC Sink Connector?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to implement the page view count. On each visit to the page, an event will be published to Kafka. The event includes pageId and Date.
I want to use the JDBC connector to increase the page count against the pageId and date.

Is it possible with JDBC Sink connector? How to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set `insert.mode` to `upsert` or `update` rather than the default.

Keep in mind that the database query will *overwrite* the count field, not increase it (as this is not how `UPDATE` queries work), so you must run some other process that will sum the total counts before writing to the database.

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#writes

https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/

You could also remove the count completely from the Kafka data, and just have a table of "page view logs", then run `SELECT date, page, COUNT(*) GROUP BY date, page;` in the database directly.